React- Removing a list item
Im just trying to remove the list item from the list using onClick with a button. I was following a book called Road to React but it still doesn't update the state of the list(returns new list without the deleted item).It appears to me that im doing something wrong in the removePerson function and using the filter function but I just cant wrap my head around what it is.

import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ljudi = [
  {
    id: '1',
    ime: 'Deni',
    prezime: 'Ivančok',
    dob: 24,
  },

  {
    id: '2',
    ime: 'Ana',
    prezime: 'Fišer',
    dob: 21,
  },

  {
    id: '3',
    ime: 'Fran',
    prezime: 'Fišer',
    dob: 21,
  },
];
function App() {
  
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(ljudi);

  const removePerson = (personToDelete) => {
    const newPeople = people.filter(
      (person) => personToDelete !== person
    );
    setPeople(newPeople);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>TIPKE</h1>
      <Lista lista={ljudi} removePerson={removePerson} />
    </>
  );
}



const Lista = ({ lista, removePerson }) =>
  lista.map(
    (covjek) => <Covjek covjek={covjek} removePerson={removePerson} />

 
  );

const Covjek = ({ covjek, removePerson }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="lista">
        <ul key="list">
          <li key="1">{covjek.id}</li>
          <li key="2">{covjek.ime}</li>
          <li key="3">{covjek.prezime}</li>
          <li key="4">{covjek.dob}</li>
        </ul>
        <button id="tipka-liste" onClick={() => removePerson(covjek)}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  ); 
};

export default App;




welcome to stackoverflow, in javascript you cannot compare objects because they are compared by memory reference and not by value (e.g. object a is not equal to object b even thought it has same properties with identical values).
In this case you are comparing the whole object, which is wrong, you should compare a string value, for example the id property, this is ideal in your case.
PS: I excluded non needed components to minimize code
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {

const [tekst, settekst] = useState('');

const TekstHandler = (event) => {
settekst(event.target.value);
};

const [people, setPeople] = useState(ljudi);

const removePerson = (personId) => {
const newPeople = people.filter(
(person) => personId !== person.id
);
setPeople(newPeople);
};

//lista property has to be `people` and not ljudi
return (
<>

<h1>TIPKE</h1>
<Lista lista={people} removePerson={removePerson} />

</>
);
}

// make sure to include the key property to `Covjek`
const Lista = ({ lista, removePerson }) =>
  lista.map(
    (covjek, i) => <Covjek key={`${i}`} covjek={covjek} removePerson={removePerson} />
 
);

const Covjek = ({ covjek, removePerson }) => {
return (
<>
<div id="lista">

<ul>
<li>{covjek.id}</li>
<li>{covjek.ime}</li>
<li>{covjek.prezime}</li>
<li>{covjek.dob}</li>
</ul>
<button onClick={() => removePerson(covjek.id)}\>
Delete
</button>
</div>

</>
);
};


Thank you for pointing that out. But it still does not remove the item by click :(

@Deni i've included more details and fixed few things, this should work. Make sure to read comments i included.

I would like to explain to you as well, when you are using react useState, you're declaring a variable that can change at runtime by rerendering the application whenever it changes, that's why whenever you update it's value, the app rerenders, but when you use an ordinary variable, you can't change it's value during runtime, so in most cases where you want data to change, you have to use react state, sometimes useRef can do the job, but i recommend using state for a beginner.

Thank you from the bottom of my heart. I would have never noticed //lista property has to be people and not ljudi lista={people}.
